# Refresh content in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I know how to refresh content that is being loaded in to a div from another page, but is there anyway to refresh content that's just sitting (already in on the same page) in a div?

**Example**

```
<?php $this = 1; ?>

<div id="refresh_this"> 
    <?php echo $this; ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to refresh content that is already on the page...it's not changing....

Comment: What is the purpose? You could refresh the page in browser.

Comment: I'm using jquery TABS, which needs a refresh to display new content, even if it doesn't change, it needs refreshed when you click on a tab. I just need to know if it's possible.

Comment: If I'm reading  your question correctly, you want the PHP code inside the div to re-execute and output a new result? The only way to do this is to use AJAX as PHP code runs on the server and not in the browser.

Comment: Is this what youre trying to achieve? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881934/reload-ajax-data-every-x-minutes-seconds-jquery

Comment: If you understand what you're asking, when you setup your tabs properly jquery ui will show the tab when the user clicks it and hide the others. There's no refreshing going on, it just modifies the css dynamically. You don't have to do anything special to get the tabs to show their content. You may want to add handlers to the tab events for custom behavior, but it's not required for the tabs control to work.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use ajax to load that content from the server again. You should look into push technology using websockets. Check out [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) for a php web socket, or do some research in web sockets in general.

A simpler approach would be polling, but it is kind of rough and not really as well rounded as web sockets. Polling is what came before sockets, and sockets are definitely the way to go.

There are two basic types of polling. Long polling and short polling.

Long polling is going to involve hitting the server and then the server fires a background thread which waits until it gets results, then returns the results at some time, which is when the poll fires again, and the server waits etc.

Short polling is where you hit the server once every x milliseconds, and then the server instantly responds and you deal with the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is a duplicate question but here goes:

```
$("#refresh_this").html('<?php echo $this; ?>');
```