# How to Refresh element in Cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

**Ex:Site Explanation:**

---

1. Two super admin SA1 SA2
2. Update button will apear on dashboard when they log into the admin side.

---

**Needed**

---

When SA1 click on Update Button it will take 15 minutes to complete the task,
      Consider while the process in progress,& SA2 logs in he should come to know SA1 
      already clicked on update button, until unless it finish off, SA2 can not click
      on it.

---

**What I did**

---

Created table 'button_status' [id, status('complete','incomplete')] whenever 
    SA1 or SA2 clicks on update button i am inserting  new record with 
    status as'incomplete' value, until that i am showing process in progress with 
    loading image and disabled the update button for both SA1 & SA2, once process 
    get finishes after 10 mints i am updating status for last record to 'complete'.
    and removing loading image and making update button enable.
    Everything is Working fine, problem is loading image or disabled button for other 
    admin who did not clicked on update button, i am not able remove it as for that i need
    to refresh the page.
    Is there any ways to show completed automatically whenever for other admin without refreshing the page after 'complete' status updated in db ?

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways of getting it straight.

**AJAX Comet**

This involves client-server implementation where client responds to events on server. More on [AJAX Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). One of  solution I have used is [meteor server](http://meteorserver.org/). It was **relatively** simple to setup, but you need access server to configure it your way. It has been discontinued though.

Pros

- You update page only when there is change. Thus taking off load of your server.
- Little or no latency

Cons

- Configuration of server-client
- Time consuming implementation

**Timed Polling**

You can poll your server once a period of time for changes. You ask custom script to return locked records in JSON or XML. Based on that you update button statuses with javascript. Deeper it is discussed [Reload AJAX data every X minutes/seconds, jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2881934/1695418)

Pros

- Easy and fast implementation

Cons

- Adds additional load on server
- Still has some latency

**Leave it as is**

If that is administrative interface and frustration on clicking already locked record is not big deal, I would leave it as it is.

**One more**

I found interesting solution for live data applications http://meteor.com/, their [SO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/meteor/info), but currently they have only mongodb support.

Comment: @icebreaker.I did the same thing wat u said 'eave it as it is', but i hope there is simple solution for this..!

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke currently I do not know simple cross browser solution.

Comment: upvoted ur answer, but this is just suggestion, i did is same as ur telling. but sending ajax request per every mints increasing lot of load on server..! probably not a bad solution.!

Comment: It depends on count of users. If you have 100 admins, comet is way to go, if 2 then refresh ;)